# How to render a component in Vue editor as custom tag?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, quill, vue-quill-editor

I have created a custom component called `<Myh id="1" />` and I created a custom tag in vue2editor. This is code:

```
    <div class="row pb-5 ">
       <div id="toolbar">
         <select class="ql-size">
          <option value="small"></option>
          <option selected></option>
          <option value="large"></option>
          <option value="huge"></option>
        </select>

        <button class="ql-bold"></button>
        <button class="ql-italic"></button>
        <button class="ql-underline"></button>
        <button class="ql-strike"></button>
        <button class="ql-color"></button>
        <button class="ql-customBtn">Custom</button>
      </div>
       <vue-editor  :editorOptions="editorSettings" v-model="article.content" class="w-100 h-100"> </vue-editor>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="updateArticle()"> Conferma </button>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';
export default {
  data: () => ({
    editorSettings: {
      modules: {
        history: { 
          delay: 2000,
          maxStack: 500,
          userOnly: true,
        },
        toolbar: {
          container: '#toolbar', 
          handlers: {
            customBtn: () => { 

              const s = window.getSelection();
              const n = s.anchorNode; 
              const o = s.anchorOffset;
              const f = s.focusOffset; 
              n.textContent = n.textContent.substring(0,o)+'<Myh id="1" />'
                
                  +n.textContent.substring(f,n.textContent.length);
            },
            redo: () => {
              console.log("redo button was clicked");
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

With another component I render the content saved in a mySQL database:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    html: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    return h({
       template: `<div> ${ this.replaceAll( this.html ) }</div>`
    });
  },
  methods:{
     htmlDecode(input) { 
      const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
      return doc.documentElement.textContent;
    },
    replaceAll(input){
      return input.replace(/&lt;Myh/g, '<Myh').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The problem is that in textarea editor I see `"<Myh id="1" />"` as text. Would it be possible to render it also during the writing phase? Or what suggestion would you give me?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it work with `v-html=`? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML